# TFS Team Web Access - Users being asked for credentials (and rejected)

Tags: tfs, ntlm, tfs-web-access

**BEFORE:** I had a TFS 2010 on a temporary test environment set up with a project and I had web users and everything worked great.

**NOW:** I've installed it on a permanent environment (same O/S, domain, everything) but any permissions I set no longer seem to have any effect.

It seems *only the service account* can access any features.
Authentication is NTLM.

Any network users I give access to are either being asked for their credentials to connect to the server and being rejected regardless (they can connect to the default IIS fine) or they get:

500 - Internal server error.
There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.

Comment: What do you mean by "I can no longer grant access to other users"? You can't, because you don't have the rights? You can't, because you get an error when you try to or you can, but the changes seem to have no effect?

Comment: Sorry I should rephrase.  I am able to setup their permissions however it doesn't appear they are having any effect.  Will edit question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ridiculous, but the problem is that the new install was on the **E:** not the **C:** so the local `NETWORK SERVICE` account (that I use as a service account for TFS) did not have access to the files/folders under `\Program Files\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2010\`